# How to run a background process on a container with kubectl exec?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, background-process

I am trying to execute a Python program as a background process inside a container with `kubectl` as shown below (the `kubectl` command is ran from the local machine):

```
kubectl exec -it <container_id> -- bash -c "cd some-dir && (python xxx.py --arg1 abc &)"
```

When I login into the container and check `ps -ef` I do not see this process running. Also, there is no output from `kubectl` command itself.

- Is the `kubectl` command issued correctly?
- Is there a better way to achieve the same?
- How can I see the output/logs printed off the background process being run?
- If I need to stop this background process after some duration, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Remember, you can use double space to break a line and you don't need to start a new paragraph because it takes too much space.

Answer (score 14):

The [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging) Wikipedia page can help; you need to redirect all three IO streams (stdout, stdin and stderr) - an example with `yes`:

```
kubectl exec pod -- bash -c "yes > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &"
```

`nohup` is not required in the above case because I did not allocate a pseudo terminal (no `-t` flag) and the shell was not interactive (no `-i` flag) so no `HUP` signal is sent to the `yes` process on session termination. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/in-which-cases-is-sighup-not-sent-to-a-job-when-you-log-out#answer-85296) answer for more details.

Redirecting `/dev/null` to stdin is not required in the above case since stdin already refers to `/dev/null` (you can see this by running `ls -l /proc/YES_PID/fd` in another shell).

To see the output you can instead redirect stdout to a file.

To stop the process you'd need to identity the PID of the process you want to stop ([pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) could be useful for this purpose) and send a fatal signal to it (`kill PID` for example).

If you want to stop the process after a fixed duration, [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) might be a better option.

Comment: This command does not work when you need to pass arguments to the background process.

Comment: I can't see why not. What command are you trying to run?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the best way to make this kind of things is adding an entry point to your container and run execute the commands there. 
Like:

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd some-dir && (python xxx.py --arg1 abc &)
./somethingelse.sh

exec "$@"
```

You wouldn't need to go manually inside every single container and run the command.

Comment: Oubhab Meskine               You really saved me dude not getting how to thank you but many many many more thanks i was stuck  like this                kubectl proxy --port=58080 & && cd /opt/helm    but your suggestion helped me to put braces like this (kubectl proxy --port=58080 &) && cd /opt/helm                 which actually worked cheers