# How to run kubectl exec on scripts that never end

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, exec, kubectl, mssql-jdbc

I have a mssql pod that I need to use the [sql_exporter](https://github.com/free/sql_exporter) to export its metrics.
I was able to set up this whole thing manually fine:

1. download the binary
2. install the package
3. run ./sql_exporter on the pod to start listening on port for metrics

I tried to automate this using `kubectl exec -it ...` and was able to do step 1 and 2. When I try to do step 3 with `kubectl exec -it "$mssql_pod_name" -- bash -c ./sql_exporter` the script just hangs and I understand as the server is just going to be listening forever, but this stops the rest of my installation scripts.

```
I0722 21:26:54.299112     435 main.go:52] Starting SQL exporter (version=0.5, branch=master, revision=fc5ed07ee38c5b90bab285392c43edfe32d271c5) (go=go1.11.3, user=root@f24ba5099571, date=20190114-09:24:06)
I0722 21:26:54.299534     435 config.go:18] Loading configuration from sql_exporter.yml
I0722 21:26:54.300102     435 config.go:131] Loaded collector "mssql_standard" from mssql_standard.collector.yml
I0722 21:26:54.300207     435 main.go:67] Listening on :9399
<nothing else, never ends>
```

Any tips on just silencing this and let it run in the background (I cannot ctrl-c as that will stop the port-listening). Or is there a better way to automate plugin install upon pod deployment? Thank you

Comment: You can try running it as Job and set a time out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### To answer your question:

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245303/609290) should help you. You should (!?) be able to use `./sql_exporter &` to run the process in the background (when **not** using `--stdin --tty`). If that doesn't work, you can try `nohup` as described by the same answer.

###### To recommend a better approach:

Using `kubectl exec` is not a good way to program a Kubernetes cluster.

`kubectl exec` is best used for debugging rather than deploying solutions to a cluster.

I assume someone has created a Kubernetes Deployment (or similar) for Microsoft SQL Server. You now want to complement that Deployment with the exporter.

You have options:

1. Augment the existing Deployment and add the `sql_exporter` as a sidecar (another container) in the Pod that includes the Microsoft SQL Server container. The exporter accesses the SQL Server via `localhost`. This is a common pattern when deploying functionality that complements an application (e.g. logging, monitoring)
2. Create a new Deployment (or similar) for the `sql_exporter` and run it as a standalone Service. Configure it scrape one|more Microsoft SQL Server instances.

Both these approaches:

- take more work but they're "more Kubernetes" solutions and provide better repeatability|auditability etc.
- require that you create a [container for `sql_exporter`](https://hub.docker.com/r/githubfree/sql_exporter) <strike>(although I assume the exporter's authors already provide this)</strike>.